# Mobile and Desktop friendly tables with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I am very newbie to grid system and struggle to understand this grid system.

What I hope to do is fit every row of table in the screen of any device from desktops to mobiles. But I couldn't manage, and even I am not sure about being on the correct road.

Here is my trial: http://jsfiddle.net/woqw0wyu/1/

How can I achieve to make this kind of table friendly for desktops and mobiles?
Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed span12">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">#</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Lat</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Lng</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Description</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Value</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Status</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Last Update</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Update Count</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>39.8677955</td>
                        <td>32.8677955</td>
                        <td>Empire State Building</td>
                        <td>45</td>
                        <td>F</td>
                        <td>2014-12-19 13:13:29 </td>
                        <td>33</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>39.8677955</td>
                        <td>32.8677955</td>
                        <td>White House Building</td>
                        <td>33</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>2014-12-19 13:13:29 </td>
                        <td>22</td>
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to have those grids the way they are you only need the smallest as they are all the same.

```
...
<thead>
   <tr>
       <th class="col-xs-1">#</th>
       <th class="col-xs-2">Lat</th>
       <th class="col-xs-2">Lng</th>
       <th class="col-xs-2">Description</th>
       <th class="col-xs-1">Value</th>
       <th class="col-xs-1">Status</th>
       <th class="col-xs-2">Last Update</th>
       <th class="col-xs-1">Update Count</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
...
```

the way it is supposed to be is this: say you want a column to be 50% width at medium screens but you want it to be 33.333% at larger screens and lastly you want it to be 100% at screens or smaller you would format it this way:

```
...
<thead>
   <tr>
       <th class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">Some Text Here</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
...
```

See updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blayderunner123/woqw0wyu/3/)
**Remember:** Wasted code is wasted money. Bootstrap is automatically set up to be responsive. It is mobile first which means it is built for mobile screens first then media attributes are added to format for larger screens

```
@media(min-width:768px){
    .div{
        /*your specific CSS for this viewport width goes here*/
    }
}
```

Could you give me alittle more and I can help you more...

Thanks!

Happy Coding!!